# What is the Mirror/PingPong clamp mode algorithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, algorithms

I do programming as a hobby, and in a dynamic system various numerical values inevitably change. Those values can be greater than or less than the expected range, in which case they need to be "wrapped" according to a "mode". I am aware of three of these wrapping modes: Clamp, which simply limits a value to a maximum or minimum, Wrap, which brings a value back around like the hand on an analog clock, and Mirror AKA Ping-Pong which is sort of like Wrap except it bounces the value back and forth as it gets further out of range. I am able to produce the Clamp and Wrap effects, but the last kind is beyond my comprehension. Does anyone know what the function would be (assuming you can use operations such as floor()) that would produce such a Mirror or Ping-Pong effect for input number A and maximum number B if the minimum number is 0?

Comment: Recommend site http://stackoverflow.com/ to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *intuition* is that "mirror" would work something like this pseudocode:

```
sub mirror(0,a,b) {
   while( a < 0 || a > b ) {
      if( a < 0 )
        a = -a;
      if( a > b )
        a = b-(a-b);
   }
   return a;
}
```

If you already have an efficient implementation of "wrap" (say, using `fmod` or `%`), you can implement "mirror" without a loop as

```
sub mirror(0,a,b) {
   a = wrap(0,a,2*b);
   if( a < b )
      return a;
   else
      return 2*b-a; // this equals b-(a-b)
 }
```

Comment: My current wrap function returns (a/b-floor(a/b))*b. Would that work? I definitely want to avoid loops. Actually, I tested the loop version and it works quite well. Your intuition is correct. I can roll with this. Thanks.

Comment: @user98973: Yes, that should work. (But if you're in a language that has `fmod` or a `%` that works on floating-point values, than that will be slightly more efficient than your divide-then-multiply implementation. You would need to divide into cases according to the sign of $a$, though).

Comment: Ehh, modulus operations are hard for someone like me who isn't so math-smart. Here is the JavaScript function which I came up with:
function mirror(a,b){
 var c=b*2,d=a/c;
 return b-((d-Math.floor(d))*c-b);
}